# How can I be sure my former employer no longer has access to my computer?

Tags: network, audit

How can I be sure now that I no longer work for a certain company that they are not accessing my computer from their side. Strange things happen ( someone remove a certain set of my friends on Facebook, then put all but one back). I also see the screen flicker like when you are getting online help. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 5):

First of all if this is your personal computer and you have serious suspicion someone is abusing your computer, file a complaint with the police. Accessing your computer without your consent is considered a crime in most countries.

If your employer did not have access before to your computer, chances are you are the victim of computer criminals. Here as well file a complaint with the police.

Then the best thing you can do is reinstall your computer from the ground up. You can backup your files though, just not the executables.

Answer (score 1):

You should change all your passwords immediately. Not sure about how to secure your computer, to be safe maybe a reformat will be good?

However, to confirm that your Facebook account has been really accessed by someone else, Facebook has an extensive monitoring account activity feature which you can use [(read page 9 of guide)](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/ownyourspace-a-guide-to-facebook-security/10150261846610766).

- Facebook *records your most recent activity and other active sessions*. If any of these look suspicious, you have the option to immediately log out that session.
- Facebook records a list of computers associated with your account and account activity. If there are computers in the list that you no longer use or have never used, you can remove them from the list.
- Facebook can send you an email/text message if a different computer or mobile device logs into your account. Or Facebook can send you a text message with a unique code to use when you log into Facebook from a different computer.

Hope it helps!